# Only last row is shown in JTable

Tags: java, jtable

I need the table to display all the rows, however it only displays the last low.

```
for (i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    Object row[] = {links.get(i).getAttribute("href"), statusCode};
    final Object rowData[][] = {row};
    final Object columnNames[] = {"Link", "Status Code"};
    DefaultTableModel listTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
    resultTable.setModel(listTableModel);
}
```

What do I do? I'm not so good with programming. Still learning.

Comment: Try using an enhanced for-loop instead of a normal one.

Comment: You need to collect the `rowData` for all rows and set them to the model after the loop. Currently, you are resetting the model every time with just a one-row table.

Comment: Do not use the DefaultTableModel > http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/extendsDefaultTableModeltocreateyourowntablemodelandbuildtablefromthat.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looping through your rows you are creating a `new DefaultTablemodel` for each row and then replacing the previous one when doing `resultTable.setModel()`. But the `TableModel` should contain the data for the entire table. So create one `TableModel` before your loop and add each row like this:

```
//create TableModel
final Object columnNames[] = {"Link", "Status Code"};
DefaultTableModel listTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames,0);
//fill the TableModel
for (i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    Object row[] = {links.get(i).getAttribute("href"), statusCode};
    listTableModel.addRow(row)
}
//associate the model with the table
resultTable.setModel(listTableModel);
```